# Why doesn't Canonical have a store in India?

Tags: canonical

I'm desperate to buy some of those great things up for sale on the Canonical Store. Is there anything that is being done to bring the store to India or have some kind of a retailer to sell the merchandise here.

At the moment the shipping costs to India is really very high and additionally we may also have to pay up customs for the product purchased.

Comment: i don't think there is a physical Canonical store in India, but online purchase should be possible at the [Canonical Store online](http://shop.canonical.com/)..

Comment: Also take a look at this brainstorm idea - [#18516: Canonical Store for India (Non-US)](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/18516/)

Comment: I agree with my friend.There should be some store in India.

Comment: To buy a £1.75 Mixed Sticker Sheet (Pack of 3 sheets).. We have to pay £6.50 for shipping and may also have to pay customs.. That's quite a lot of Indian Rupees.. May be fans here will just have to wait it out :'(

Comment: Or you could organise and place one huge order. This way you pay shipping only once and devide it between all fans.

Comment: China and India are the biggest adopters of Ubuntu and the country with most potential for business for Ubuntu. Ignoring a buying power democracy like India and giving precedence to China speaks of narrow vision of Ubuntu policy makers, am sorry to say.

Comment: If Raspberry Pi can do it, so can Canonical..
(Yes Raspberry costs double of what it costs in the US and UK)..
Canonical also can come up something of that sort.. It'd be ok to pay double than to pay 7-8times more of what the merchandise actually costs..

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this same exact question could be posed by Ubuntu users in any other country. Now that China has Ubuntu stores, everyone else wants them. Opening up stores takes time, and canonical has to decide where they want to put they're money to make a store. They'll build stores wherever the most loyal Ubuntu users are - and if that's in India, then so be it. You should contribute to the thread on Ubuntu brainstorm. This is not really they type of question that belongs on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Opening a new business in India is always difficult. This is perhaps a question that is borderline related to bureaucratic policies and Ubuntu!

[Ease of doing business](http://www.doingbusiness.org/rankings)

[Wikipedia entry](http://www.doingbusiness.org/rankings)

That says a lot!

And I am not sure about India being one of the biggest adopters of Ubuntu/linux. The whole idea of owning a laptop/computer, for instance, has been catching up for what, 5-7 years now? So it is rather obvious that the first OS anyone is exposed to at home is Windows. And most people get ensconced in windows and don't really look around.

But there is a lot of hope as seen in this [search result](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=linux+in+india&oq=linux+in+india&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i30l2j0i5i30.1341.2616.0.2731.14.12.0.0.0.0.229.1798.0j9j2.11.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.n4Ntw-AStHc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=ee2cd9b81b9db13c&bpcl=35466521&biw=1360&bih=537) from google.

I hope that answers your question to some extent!

And btw, I am Indian!